# Saving Relationships in Laravel on the go

Tags: laravel

I have a user model that is related to a enduser model with a hasOne relationship.
I want to save the inputs of a form field in both user and enduser model in one go. 
here is my code;

```
    $user = new User();
    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = $request->password;
    $user->enduser->username = $request->username;
    $user->save();

    return user;
```

my relationships are

```
Class User extends Authenticable
{
       public function enduser()
       {
         return $this->hasOne('App\Enduser');
       }
}
```

my migration for users is thus

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('phone_number');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->enum('roles',['admin', 'enduser', 'organization', 'radio', 'employee'])->nullable();


        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();


    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

and for enduser is thus

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('endusers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('lga')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('state')->nullable();
        $table->string('username');

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('endusers');
}
```

i get an error that says 'unknown column 'username' in where clause'. How can i save such relationship?

Comment: Show the relationship

Comment: as well as add the models source code

Comment: Looking at the relation, Laravel when building the related query will look for a `enduser_id` column... is it the right foreign key? That may be the cause of your `unknown column in where clause`

Comment: I feel so dumb. I totally forgot to add a foreign key to my user model. Thank you @IlGala for that!

Comment: @PatrickObafemi that's why SO exists! To make people fell dumb :P

Joking... Glad to help

Comment: The columns for `User` and `EndUser` are the same?

Comment: @MateusJunges i already edited it

Comment: What do you mean wiht _save the inputs of a form field in both user and enduser model in one go_? Every time that a user has been registered, you want to create a new `EndUser` with the same data?

Comment: @MateusJunges Yes that's what i mean

Comment: So i think you can use [Laravel observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers). I'll add an answer

Answer (score 2):

Your user model should look like this.

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name','last_name','phone', 'email', 'password',
    ];


    public function enduser() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\EndUser');
    }
}
```

and your EndUser model should look like this

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EndUser extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
    ];


    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Then you can write this code in your controller

```php
//first becrypt your password
$request->merge('password',bcrypt($request->password));

$user = User::create(
    $request->only(['first_name','last_name','phone','email','password'])
);

$user->enduser->create([$request->username]);

return $user;
```

Answer (score 1):

Therefore, in order to accomplish what you're trying to do, you can do first create the user then associate the enduser with it by doing the following:

```
$user = new User();
$user->first_name = $request->first_name;
$user->last_name = $request->last_name;
$user->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
$user->email = $request->email;
$user->password = $request->password;
$user->save();

$endUser = new EndUser();
$endUser->username = $request->username;
$user->enduser()->save($endUser);

return $user;
```

However, prior to doing this, you must ensure your User and enduser models have their relationships set up correctly.

Comment: Yeah i already got it on my own but i gave you a tick because of your effort. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve it using [laravel observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers):

```sh
php artisan make:observer UserObserver --model User
```

This command will create a `UserObserver.php` file inside `app/Observers` folder.

Add this to the `created` function:

```php
public function created(User $user)
{
    EndUser::create([
        'username' => $user->username,
        'user_id'  => $user->id,
    ]);
}
```

You also need to edit the `AppServiceProvider` file, inside the `app/Providers` folder. Add this to the `boot` method:

```php
public function boot()
{
    User::observe(UserObserver::class);
}
```

Now, every time that a `User` get registered, it will create a `EndUser` with the user data.

Hope it helps.